# keyboard shortcut for step out while debugging in rstudio

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

When I'm debugging, every time, I make a change to the source code, I find myself doing the following since it says, "Debug location is approximate because the source is not available.". Is this 3-step process necessary? Is there an easier way?

```
> debugSource('~/Desktop/foo1.R')
> debug(myfun1)
> myfun1()
```

Comment: I would suggest you dig into other ways of debugging. Try http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/R-debug-tools.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that this is, what you want, but since you use the tag `rstudio`, it might help.

Clicking in the left border of the script window in RStudio (next to the line numbers) creates a break point. It is marked by a red circle (it it's inside a function) or a red dot (otherwise). If you now click the source button in RStudio, `debugSource` is run. If the program encounters a breakpoint, it stops and you are able to examine the state of the program. A breakpoint inside a function stops the code when the function is run (and not when it is sourced). The breakpoint will also work when you run the function from the console as in your example.

The breakpoint remains intact when you change your code. So you have, of course, to source your code after every change, but you don't need to rerun `debug` every time.

For more information on debugging with RStudio, the following link might be helpful: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200713843-Debugging-with-RStudio